# Cannot redirect to specific path name in urls.py

Tags: python, django, redirect, path, pathname

I have a issue in django project where I want to redirect to a specific path using its name. My code looks like this. It doesn't redirect to a path name but It redirect towards http://127.0.0.1:8000/  perfectly. I googled and also searched it in stack overflow but I didn't find any question related to this. What can be the problem and solution to it. I followed tutorial and there his code his working fine and redirecting well.

***urls.py***

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='myhomepage'),
    path('order', order),
    path('signup', signup)
]
```

And in views.py the code goes like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models.product import Product
from .models.category import Category
from .models.customer import Customer


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    # calling get_all_product() method from products
    products = None
    categories = Category.get_all_categories()
    category_id_from_server = request.GET.get('category')
    if category_id_from_server:
        products = Product.get_all_product_by_category_id(category_id_from_server)
    else:
        products = Product.get_all_product()
    data = {}
    data['products'] = products
    data['categories'] = categories
    return render(request, 'index.html', data)


def order(request):
    return render(request, 'orders.html')


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'signup.html')
    else:
        postdata = request.POST
        first_name = postdata.get('firstname')
        last_name = postdata.get('lastname')
        phone_number = postdata.get('phone')
        email_id = postdata.get('email')
        pass_word = postdata.get('password')

        # Validation
        error_message = None
        formdata = {
            'firstname_formdata': first_name,
            'lastname_formdata': last_name,
            'phonenumber_formdata': phone_number,
            'emailid_formdata': email_id
        }
        if not first_name:
            error_message = "First Name Required !!!"
        elif len(first_name) < 4:
            error_message = "First Name should be more than 4 character."
        elif not last_name:
            error_message = "Last Name Required !!!"
        elif len(last_name) < 4:
            error_message = "last Name should be more than 4 character."
        elif not phone_number:
            error_message = "Phone Number Required !!!"
        elif len(phone_number) < 5:
            error_message = "Phone Number should be more than 5 character."
        elif not email_id:
            error_message = "Email ID Required !!!"
        elif not pass_word:
            error_message = "Password Required !!!"
        elif len(pass_word) < 4:
            error_message = "Password should be more than 4 character."

        # Saving in Database
        # customer object = Customer (customer model name = Post data)
        if not error_message:
            customerobj = Customer(first_name=first_name,
                                   last_name=last_name,
                                   phone=phone_number,
                                   email=email_id,
                                   password=pass_word)
            customerobj.register()
            return redirect('myhomepage')
        else:
            data = {
                'error': error_message,
                'formdata_key': formdata
            }
            return render(request, 'signup.html', data)
```

This should redirect me to the homepage but it don't redirect as required.

but if I do

```
return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/ ')
```

It will redirect as required.

Comment: Do you get any error instead of redirect? What happens instead of redirect?

Comment: if you want to redirect the user in your home template, just use redirect(' / ')

Comment: No any error. But it will redirect toward /signup page listed in the action="/signup" of the form.

Comment: @SerioUs thank you. That worked but why the name of the path not working?

Comment: @MilanAdhikari good

Comment: @MilanAdhikari i didn't use the home name for redirect before. there are no need to use home page name for redirect, just a slash it will make the job done.